# How to get the selected values of individual dropdown when multiple dropownlist are present in mvc form

Tags: forms, model-view-controller

I have multiple dropdownlist in a **mvc form** as below inside
@Html.BeginForm()

```
 <div class="form-group">
              @Html.dropdownlistfor(u=>u.medinfovalue,Model.MedInfoData,new{@class="col-12"})
              @Html.HiddenFor(u=>u.medinfoText)
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
         @Html.dropdownlistfor(u=>u.colinfovalue,Model.colInfoData,new{@class="col-12"})
         @Html.HiddenFor(u=>u.colinfoText)
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
          @Html.dropdownlistfor(u=>u.stuinfovalue,Model.stuInfoData,new{@class="col-12"})
          @Html.HiddenFor(u=>u.stuinfoText)
    </div>
```

But when the html is rendering i can see the 1st hidden textbox value is taking all the dropdown values appended and next 2 hidden values have no values.
Please let me know where i am going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing here. Is the stuff you have prepended with '@' syntax for a template engine? If so, which one?

Comment: I m creating a mvc form

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model has properties like:

```
public int medinfovalue { get; set; }
public int colinfovalue { get; set; }
public int stuinfovalue { get; set; }
```

you need to change it to int[] like:

```
public int[] medinfovalues { get; set; }
public int[] colinfovalues { get; set; }
public int[] stuinfovalues { get; set; }
```

or string -> string[], whatever ..... and later view ofc:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      @Html.Dropdownlistfor(u=>u.medinfovalues,Model.MedInfoData,new{@class="form-control", multiple="multiple"})
      @Html.HiddenFor(u=>u.medinfoText)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      @Html.Dropdownlistfor(u=>u.colinfovalues,Model.colInfoData,new{@class="form-control", multiple="multiple"})
      @Html.HiddenFor(u=>u.colinfoText)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      @Html.Dropdownlistfor(u=>u.stuinfovalues,Model.stuInfoData,new{@class="form-control", multiple="multiple"})
      @Html.HiddenFor(u=>u.stuinfoText)
</div>
```

unfotunetly this will create ugly listbox like:
[image]

which is why i recommend to use bootstrap-select package:
[bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/)

to have a list like below you need to import bootstrap-select lib and change class from "form-control" to "selectpicker":

[image]

```
@Html.Dropdownlistfor(u=>u.medinfovalues,Model.MedInfoData,new{@class="selectpicker", multiple="multiple"})
```